# Is it possible to limit access to files hosted on a third party server that i control?

Tags: wordpress, networking, html5-video

I am simply wondering if it is possible to limit access to files hosted on a third party server to my website only?

Since I would not call myself a programmer I suppose some context is in order...

I am building a website using Wordpress and I plan to display quite a few videos on my website. If I were to purchase space on a third party server and upload a file such as www.thisistheserver.com/somevideofile.mp4 would it be possible to only allow that file to be accessed by a list of whitelisted ip addresses?

The goal is to upload a video specifically an mp4 since and have it display only on my website. So guys is this possible?

Answers to tell me I am way out of my depth and should hire an actual programmer will be accepted as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. Wordpress has basic plugins which allow you to password protect your site from a public facing perspective.

In addition, the majority of server hosts will provide software (e.g. cPanel) which allows you to restrict access to the server to white listed IPs only.

I don't know if a dedicated programmer would be required, if you've got some time and the desire to learn I think you'll be grand.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer Andy. I just wanted to make sure this was possible before I made a purchase.